# Error installing Cassandra on Mac with Java 13

Tags: cassandra

I am using macOS Mojave My Java version is 13.0

I am a beginner in Cassandra please help me to fix this I read lot of post regarding this error but all are old not working with the current version

```
webz$ java -version
    java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

cassendra error :-

```
Webzs-MacBook-Pro:~ webz$ cassandra 
Webzs-MacBook-Pro:~ webz$ [0.001s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/usr/local/cassandra/bin/../logs/gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jvm.options file of Cassandra, check if this is enabled.

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC
```

If yes, then you can comment that and replace with this

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

This is because support for UseParNewGC has been disabled in Java 10. 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151084

You may run into other issues also because of your java version as released versions of Cassandra support only Java 8. The support for higher versions will be in Cassandra 4.0 but that isn't released yet.

Answer (score 0):

As it states in the [Installation prerequisites](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html), Cassandra 3.x (or earlier versions) only work with Java 8.

Cassandra 4.0.2 added full support for Java 11 only recently ([CASSANDRA-16894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16894)). This means that C* 4.x will work with either Java 8 or Java 11.

Cassandra will not work with Java 13. For what it's worth, we are working on supporting Java 17 LTS in the next major release of Cassandra ([CASSANDRA-16895](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16895)). Cheers!